# Using 1-N Relationships with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

After defining a simple 1-n relation with the following classes:

```
class User(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'user'
UserID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
Name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
emails = db.relationship('email')

def __init__(self, username):
    self.Name = username


class Email(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'email'
    EmailID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    Email = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    User = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('user.UserID'))

    def __init__(self, mail):
    self.Email = mail
```

I want to create a user and add it some mails then save it to the db using:

```
username = "serkan1"
newuser = User(username)
newuser.emails[Email(Email='serkan@ismygirl.com'),Email(Email = 'eddfsdfq@ff.com')]
db.session.add(product)
db.session.commit()
return "ok"
```

But i get the error:

```
ArgumentError: relationship 'emails' expects a class or a mapper argument (received: <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.schema.Table'>)
```

How can i simply create a user,add it some emails with 1-n schema and save it to the db?

Answer (score 5):

Try changing this line:

```
emails = db.relationship('email')
```

to:

```
emails = db.relationship('Email')
```

Which will reference your `Email` class instead of your `email` table as the error message describes.

Comment: I had the same exact issue because I was also referencing the table name instead of the ORM class name. Thanks!